# Dim 4k LCD panel in response to ambient light

Tags: sensors, lcd, display

Warning: I'm completely new to Arduino, and not even sure if it's the right solution here.

I'm trying to make a better digital picture frame. Got almost all the way there by just buying a nice flat-bezel 4k display, connecting a chromecast, and putting a picture frame on it. Voila!

But I want it to adjust its brightness in response to ambient light -- and turn itself off when the room is dark. So now I need something to check a light sensor and control screen brightness.

Is it possible (and does it make sense) to disassemble the monitor, wire up the LCD panel to a controller with arduino, add in a light sensor, and try to tackle it that way? Is there a better way?

Would greatly appreciate any recommendations / suggestions / ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe the display already has an auto-brightness function

Comment: check if the display allows lan remote control

Comment: Does the display have any button or such for controlling the brightness?

Comment: Well,you might need to provide an image or specs of this LCD, but assuming the worst case that it's just a basic LCD screen you will need to disassemble it and you will make a lot of things and It may be hard for you, as you said that you are completely new to Arduino.